Are step functions used in double integral definition bounded?
Definition of  double integral on a rectangle  can  be defined  by using step functions, for example in Apostol Calculus Book. In this case the  definition for step function is: * a  function $s$ defined from (closed) rectangle $R=[a,b]\times [c,d]$ to the set of real number is a step function if there exists a partition P of R such that in  each open sub rectangle the  function $s$ is constant*.
In addition, in that book, the  integral  of  steep function  on a rectangle is defined like  the sum of the  volume (with signal) of rectangular boxes which bases are the sub-rectangles generated by partition $P$. $$\int \int_R s(x,y)dx dy= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{m}c_{ij}\Delta x_i \Delta y_j$$ where $c_{ij}$ is the constant  value of $s$ in the open sub-rectangle $ (x_{i-1}, x_i) \times (y_{j-1}, y_j)$.
My questions are: (a) Is it necessary that $s$ function to be bounded in that definition? (b) If answer to my before  question is "not", how can I proof that a step function (like I will give below) is integrable on $R$ when we use Riemann Sums  definition like in Apostol Analysis Book?
I am  thinking  for example in the function $$s(x,y)=\begin{cases} 1/x & \text{ if } y=0 \text{ and } x>0 \\ 2 & \text{ in other case }. \end{cases}    $$
under definition above  $s$ is an integrable step function (its integral is 2), but how  can I give the same answer  by using  definition  using Riemann Sums?
I have  read on the  sets of Zero Content, but theorem related to the  existence of  the integral assumes that  function $s$ is bounded on $R$.
